# R: zoo object vector explanation. Referring to ..$ : NULL. compared to ..$ : chr

Tags: r, vector, null, zoo

I have two zoo objects and I am wondering, why the first zoo object shows

`..$ : NULL`
when the second one shows

```
..$ : chr [1:2266] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

instead.
What does this mean in this case? And how could I change
"..$ : chr [1:2266] "1" "2" "3" "4" ..."    to   "..$ : NULL" in the second object?

Background: I am conducting an eventstudy (package eventstudies) and I get the error:

`Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : subscript out of bounds`

One of the possible problems could be the formatting of the data. The object "OtherReturns" is used as example data in the package. I am hoping to resolve the error by understanding more about zoo objects. Yet, I could not understand the formatting difference between the two following objects:

```
> str(OtherReturns)
‘zoo’ series from 2010-07-01 to 2013-03-28
  Data: num [1:720, 1:4] -1.1568 -0.2727 -0.0229 1.01 -0.9107 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "NiftyIndex" "CallMoneyRate" "SP500" "USDINR"
  Index:  Date[1:720], format: "2010-07-01" "2010-07-02" "2010-07-05" "2010-07-06" "2010-07-07" "2010-07-08" "2010-07-09" "2010-07-12" ...


> str(zoo_SP500)
‘zoo’ series from 2007-01-03 to 2015-12-31
  Data: num [1:2266, 1:2] 1417 1418 1410 1413 1412 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2266] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "SP500_Closing" "Index_return"
  Index:  Date[1:2266], format: "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-09" "2007-01-10" "2007-01-11" "2007-01-12" ...
```

At the first glance, both objects look the same in this regard:

```
> head(OtherReturns,3)
            NiftyIndex CallMoneyRate     SP500    USDINR
2010-07-01 -1.15678265            NA        NA 0.3009785
2010-07-02 -0.27267977            NA -1.341017 0.0000000
2010-07-05 -0.02291607            NA        NA 0.4070272

> head(zoo_SP500,3)
           SP500_Closing Index_return
2007-01-03       1416.60   -0.1198618
2007-01-04       1418.34    0.1228293
2007-01-05       1409.71   -0.6084578
```

Any help and explanations much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Those are just the row names. They don't really matter.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, you are right and after setting rownames to NULL error still not solved. I guess I need to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example that allows someone else to copy the code into their session and see the same error.  See the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.